# Why the transform is moving first to the target object position and then changing position to the new radius set instead moving to the new radius?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

what I want to do is when I change the radius at runtime from 5 to 1 or any new radius the transform will smooth move to the new radius position from it's current position and if the transform is rotating around the target then keep rotating and also change to the new radius.

but what it does is the transform first moving to the target and then from the target "jumping" to the new radius position. and I don't want it to move first to the target position but to move to the new radius considering the transform rotation around the target.

In the Update in line 69 I'm setting the radiusPosition.

```
if (target != null)
        {
            if (dc != null)
            {
                radiusPosition = new Vector3(target.position.x, 
                    target.position.y + dc.yRadius, target.position.z + dc.xRadius);

                radius = dc.xRadius;
            }
            else
            {
                radiusPosition = new Vector3(target.position.x, target.position.y, target.position.z + radius);
            }
        }
```

and then if there is a new radius then it should move to the new radius position: line 118 to 122:

```
if (transform.position != radiusPosition)
            {
                float step = movingToRadiusSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
                transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position,
                    radiusPosition , step);
```

the full code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RotateAroundTarget : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Target")]
    public Transform target;
    [Header("Rotating Speed")]
    public float rotatingSpeed;
    [Header("First Move To Radius Settings")]
    public float movingToRadiusSpeed;
    public bool moveToRadius = false;
    [Header("Axis Settings")]
    public Vector3 axis;
    [Header("Height Settings")]
    public bool randomHeight;
    public float setRandomHeight = 1;
    [Header("Radius Settings")]
    public float radius;
    [Header("Reference To DrawCircle Script")]
    public DrawCircle dc;
    [Header("Reference To Linerenderer")]
    public LineRenderer lineRenderer;

    private float lastRadius;
    private float t = 0.0f;
    public float upperLimit, lowerLimit, delay;
    private float prevHeight;
    private Vector3 radiusPosition;
    private Vector3[] positions;

    private void Start()
    {
        if (dc != null)
        {
            lastRadius = dc.xRadius;
            radius = dc.xRadius;
        }
        else
        {
            lastRadius = radius;
        }

        if (lineRenderer != null)
        {
            GetLinePointsInWorldSpace();
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (target != null)
        {
            if (dc != null)
            {
                radiusPosition = new Vector3(target.position.x, 
                    target.position.y + dc.yRadius, target.position.z + dc.xRadius);

                radius = dc.xRadius;
            }
            else
            {
                radiusPosition = new Vector3(target.position.x, target.position.y, target.position.z + radius);
            }
        }

        if (moveToRadius == false)
        {
            if (target != null)
            {
                transform.RotateAround(target.position, axis, rotatingSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            }

            if (randomHeight)
            {
                t += Time.deltaTime;

                if (t > delay)
                {
                    prevHeight = setRandomHeight;
                    setRandomHeight = Random.Range(lowerLimit, upperLimit);
                    t = 0;
                }

                var tt = transform.position;
                tt.y = Mathf.Lerp(prevHeight, setRandomHeight, t);
                transform.position = tt;
            }
        }

        if (dc != null)
        {
            if (lastRadius != dc.xRadius)
            {
                moveToRadius = true;

                lastRadius = dc.xRadius;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (lastRadius != radius)
            {
                moveToRadius = true;

                lastRadius = radius;
            }
        }

        if (moveToRadius)
        {
            if (transform.position != radiusPosition)
            {
                float step = movingToRadiusSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
                transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position,
                    radiusPosition , step);
                
            }
            else
            {
                moveToRadius = false;
            }
        }
    }

    Vector3[] GetLinePointsInWorldSpace()
    {
        positions = new Vector3[lineRenderer.positionCount];
        //Get the positions which are shown in the inspector 
        lineRenderer.GetPositions(positions);


        //the points returned are in world space
        return positions;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just calculate the following

`nextRotatedPosition` This will be your position after you call rotate

`distanceToTarget` This is the absolute distance from your object to the target

`vectorToTarget` This is a normalized vector which points the target from the object

`distanceChange = distanceToTarget - newRadius` This is the amount to change to

`newTransform = nextRotatedPosition + (vectorToTarget * distanceChange)`

Answer (score 0):

Working code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RotateAroundPoint : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform target;
    public Vector3 axis = Vector3.up;
    public float radius = 2.0f;
    public float radiusSpeed = 0.5f;
    public float rotationSpeed = 80.0f;
    public bool randomHeight = false;
    public float upperLimit, lowerLimit, delay;
    public float setRandomHeight = 1;

    private float t = 0.0f;
    private float prevHeight;

    private void Start()
    {
        transform.position = (transform.position - target.position).normalized * radius + target.position;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (randomHeight)
        {
            t += Time.deltaTime;

            if (t > delay)
            {
                prevHeight = setRandomHeight;
                setRandomHeight = Random.Range(lowerLimit, upperLimit);
                t = 0;
            }

            var tt = transform.position;
            tt.y = Mathf.Lerp(prevHeight, setRandomHeight, t);
            transform.position = tt;
        }

        transform.RotateAround(target.position, axis, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        var desiredPosition = (transform.position - target.position).normalized * radius + target.position;
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, desiredPosition, Time.deltaTime * radiusSpeed);
    }
}
```